# Detect black pixel in image iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, colors, pixel

As of now I am searching every pixel 1 by 1 checking the color and seeing if it's black... if it isn't I move on to the next pixel. This is taking forever as I can only check approx. 100 pixels per second (speeding up my NSTimer freezes the app because it can't check fast enough.) So is there anyway I can just have Xcode return all the pixels that are black and ignore everything else so I only have to check those pixels and not every pixel. I am trying to detect a black pixel furthest to the left on my image.

Here is my current code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.01
                                             target: self
                                           selector:@selector(onTick:)
                                           userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
    y1 = 0;
    x1 = 0;
    initialImage = 0;
    height1 = 0;
    width1 = 0;
}

-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
    if (initialImage != 1) {
        /*
        IMAGE INITIALLY GETS SET HERE... "image2.image = [blah blah blah];" took this out for non disclosure reasons
        */
        initialImage = 1;
    }
    //image2 is the image I'm checking the pixels of.
    width1 = (int)image2.size.width;
    height1 = (int)image2.size.height;
    CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image2.CGImage));
    const UInt32 *pixels = (const UInt32*)CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData);
    if ( (pixels[(x1+(y1*width1))]) == 0x000000) { //0x000000 is black right?
        NSLog(@"black!");
        NSLog(@"x = %i", x1);
        NSLog(@"y = %i", y1);
    }else {
        NSLog(@"val: %lu", (pixels[(x1+(y1*width1))]));
        NSLog(@"x = %i", x1);
        NSLog(@"y = %i", y1);
        x1 ++;
        if (x1 >= width1) {
            y1 ++;
            x1 = 0;
        }
    }
    if (y1 > height1) {
        /*
        MY UPDATE IMAGE CODE GOES HERE (IMAGE CHANGES EVERY TIME ALL PIXELS HAVE BEEN CHECKED
        */
        y1 = 0;
        x1 = 0;
    }
```

Also what if a pixel is really close to black but not perfectly black... Can I add a margin of error in there somewhere so it will still detect pixels that are like 95% black? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you using a timer at all? Why not just have a double for loop in your function that loops over all possible x- and y-coordinates in the image? Surely that would be waaaay faster than only checking at most 100 pixels per second. You would want to have the x (width) coordinates in the outer loop and the y (height) coordinates in the inner loop so that you are effectively scanning one column of pixels at a time from left to right, since you are trying to find the leftmost black pixel.

Also, are you sure that each pixel in your image has a 4-byte (Uint32) representation? A standard bitmap would have 3 bytes per pixel. To check if a pixel is close to black, you would just examine each byte in the pixel separately and make sure they are all less than some threshold.

EDIT: OK, since you are using UIGetScreenImage, I'm going to assume that it is 4-bytes per pixel.

```
const UInt8 *pixels = CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData);
UInt8 blackThreshold = 10; // or some value close to 0
int bytesPerPixel = 4;
for(int x = 0; x < width1; x++) {
  for(int y = 0; y < height1; y++) {
    int pixelStartIndex = (x + (y * width1)) * bytesPerPixel;
    UInt8 alphaVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex]; // can probably ignore this value
    UInt8 redVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 1];
    UInt8 greenVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 2];
    UInt8 blueVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 3];
    if(redVal < blackThreshold && blueVal < blackThreshold && greenVal < blackThreshold) {
      //This pixel is close to black...do something with it
    }
  }
}
```

If it turns out that bytesPerPixel is 3, then change that value accordingly, remove the alphaVal from the for loop, and subtract 1 from the indices of the red, green, and blue values.

Also, my current understanding is that UIGetScreenImage is considered a private function that Apple may or may not reject you for using.

Comment: How can I change it to 3bit? The image is just a screenshot of a section on the screen that I captured using `CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage();` Also I'm completely open to not using the timer, I am not to familiar with while-infinite loops, I know how to set them up I just rarely use them so I guess I forgot haha. Also, is there a method to detect all pixels in the array and only return the x and y coordinates of those that are black rather than checking each one individually (even if I'm using a loop?)

Comment: There is nothing infinite about the loop, it just goes over the width and height of the image. One way or another you're going to have to check all of the pixels. There's no other way to figure out which one is black. Give me a second and I'll update my post with some code.

Comment: Awesome code! Thankyou! And sorry I was thinking of the loop that is like while i<(i+1) { i++; } I dunno haha! It's been forever since I've done a loop I always use if else statements /: Thanks for the code though! let me test it!

Comment: My image is 150x170 pixels so this method takes a while! I don't care too much about the quality of the image so what is the proper way to resize it for this pixel checking method? Right now it's just a UIImage. I was thinking something along the lines of`CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` but I don't think that will scale it, just crop it..

Comment: Your method works great I just need a good way of resizing my image so I don't have to check tens of thousands of pixels... I want to scale it to 15x17 instead of 150x170, the black regions are large enough that after scaling I will still have black pixels. (btw I did have to change it to bytesPerPixel3 and ignore alpha!

Comment: Ahhh the more I began testing it, the more I realized your method isn't seeming to work. It will pick up black pixels even when there are only white pixels on the image... I tried threshold 0, 1, 10, 50, 100, and changing the bytes per pixel to 3 and 4 (with adjusting the redial, greenval, and blueval accordingly as well.)

Comment: Maybe you can edit your post to include what your code looks like now

Comment: Is there anyway I can have it NSLOG the color RGB of a pixel without separating it into different values and comparing it to a threshold? I can just look at the NSLOG and check how close the RGB string is to #000000

Comment: I'm trying the following but it returns weird values that don't seem like hexadecimal values or any other way of formatting color that I've seen before:

`
NSLog(@"val: %lu", (pixels[(x1+(y1*width1))]));
`

Comment: Oh it is 4byte not 3byte but Alpha is the last one.. its RGBA not ARGB so that was messing with the code some but it's still not working 100% for me /:

Comment: Took a lot but I switched back to ARGB messed around with some stuff and got it working.. P.s. the R G B and A values come at as 0-225

Comment: how fast is this function running now on that size of image on your phone? did you get an answer for the loop for the downsampled image? i'm thinking you could probably set a downsample factor and loop through a smaller number of pixels instead of downsampling the image and then looping. sounds like you'd be wasting time allocating memory/writing.

Comment: Edit: I think this was wrong... It's been a while since I've worked with pixel stuff but I'm pretty sure it's BGR not RGB...

Comment: I am stuck with finding number of white pixels from drawing context. Now its working fantastic with this code. Thanks for sharing this code.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw hey can you give me idea how to get the left and right most point of black color from imageview...i get the pixel of that after that what to do?

Comment: @UIAdam hey help me for find the left most point of black color ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on pixel-level image processing, but my first thought is: why are you using a timer to do this?  That incurs lots of overhead and makes the code less clear to read.  (I think it also renders it thread-unsafe.)  The overhead is not just from the timer itself but because you are doing all the data setup each time through.

How about using a loop instead to iterate over the pixels?

Also, you are leaking imageData (since you create it with a "Copy" method and never release it).  Currently you are doing this once *per timer fire* (and your imageData is probably pretty big if you are working on all but the tiniest images), so you are probably leaking *tons* of memory.

Comment: How can I stop my memory leaks? I've never had to deal with that in the past but I can see how it would become a problem with something like this? Can you give me a mini lesson? :)

Comment: You really, really need to read the Core Foundation Memory Management guide (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html), at least the first three sections.  In this case, the short of it is to call CGDataProviderRelease(imageData) at the end of your method.

Comment: Oops, I meant CFRelease(imageData)... wires crossed in brain.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you should be doing this with a timer (or no reason I can think of anyway!).

How big are your images? It should be viable to process the entire image in a single loop reasonably quickly.